# MariaDB 10.5 refusing remote connections

Tags: mariadb, remote-access

I've gone through a lot of tutorials and questions and I still can't get it to work.

I installed MariaDB 10.5 on a Debian 11 server. We changed its IP address yesterday and since then we cannot do a remote connection. The database answers "Access Denied to user@host on database"

We created some users to test:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'host.domain.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'something';
```

**Does local connections work?**

Yes, as we granted the privileges to localhost access.

**Did you verify the users were added correctly?**

I think so:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE Host <> 'localhost';

+--------------+------------------------+
| User         | Host                   |
+--------------+------------------------+
| user         | host.domain.com        |
| root         | 127.0.0.1              |
| root         | ::1                    |
+--------------+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Have you unblocked the firewall?**

Yes, as we get Access Denied error. So we are getting into the database.

**Did you check the my.cnf file for correct settings?**

Incorrect settings in my.cnf (/etc/my.cnf) can cause it to refuse connections. These are skip-networking and bind-address. My file looks like this:

```
#
# This group is read by the client library
# Use it for option that affect all clients, but not the server
#
[client]

#
# 
#
[client-mariadb]
```

The server file contains the bind-address directive to allow remote connections

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

**Did you check the other config files?**

Yes.

**Does telnet work?**

Yes.

**Did you remember to restart?**

Yes. I restarted using this between all attempts:

```
service mariadb restart
```

We cannot find what is wrong with this server.

Comment: You don't show how the client is connecting, or where the client is running. Is it on `host.domain.com`? Or is it on localhost?

Comment: Does your new server (IP) reverse DNS resolve host.domain.com correctly to the origin where you are connected from? Is `skip-name-resolve` enabled on this server?